# Details lost after segmentation

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, deep-learning, python-imaging-library

I applied a DNN for segmentation task. Though the object has been segmented well but the details of the object in the segmentation mask are lost e.g. the arms are not clearly visible. Here is a sample image on which I tried my segmentation net(image credits:Google images):

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrRFi.jpg)

The segmented image of the above image is this:

[segmented image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf5lv.png)

Now, you can see the details in the segmented image are totally lost. How can I fine-tune the segmentation using post processing techniques in order to get back the details?

Comment: You don't get the details from segmentation. That's how it works unless you are looking to segment parts of the body. And no way you're going to get back the original image.

Comment: That is quite a complex problem, but you can take a look to research papers such as [this one](http://xiaoyongshen.me/papers/deepmatting.pdf) which is done for portraits, but they manage to get a lot of details. I do not think it is an easy solution though.